# How make a react-native package using java?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to reuse some code from android app programmed by java. And i want to reuse in a React-Native app. How can i create a interface or a funcionality in java and export to a react-native package?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Native Module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) android for use java programming through react-native

and you can use the third party to create Native Module [react-native-create-bridge](https://github.com/peggyrayzis/react-native-create-bridge)